# ASP .NET Web API controller action's parameter is null but ModelState.IsValid still true, why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Question says it all, I have a Web API controller action, that takes a POCO. It's a POST action, and I'm intentionally not posting the parameter to the action, however the ModelState.IsValid property still shows true. Why would that be? Is there an attribute that I have to set on the controller action and its parameters to enforce the validation?

Answer (score 1):

Null is a valid value for a object. Make the properties in the POCO [Required] to enforce checks.

Comment: Well, an object can be a instance of an object but also null. It just points in to nothing. What are the properties of thingy? [Required] tells the validation engine to see if the actual value is in there.

Comment: Thingy is any arbitrary model with fields (strings, value types, other models). Maybe my question should be to ask what the correct pattern should be for actions to check for null parameters? The autogenerated code from MVC 4 in 2012 doesn't include a check for null. So should I be adding one, or am I missing another feature of the MVC famework?

Comment: Marking one of the fields within Thingy as [Required] does not lead to ModelState.IsValid being false when thingy == null. I guess I just don't understand how you're supposed to delcare that an action parameter must be non null to be valid. Seems to me that it should work that way out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. You have a valid concern. Please have a look at this:

https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/

Data-Annotations to the rescue:

```
public class ValidateActionParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute  
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            var parameters = descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var argument = context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name];

                EvaluateValidationAttributes(parameter, argument, context.ModelState);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    private void EvaluateValidationAttributes(ParameterInfo parameter, object argument, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var validationAttributes = parameter.CustomAttributes;

        foreach (var attributeData in validationAttributes)
        {
            var attributeInstance = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(parameter, attributeData.AttributeType);

            var validationAttribute = attributeInstance as ValidationAttribute;

            if (validationAttribute != null)
            {
                var isValid = validationAttribute.IsValid(argument);
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(parameter.Name, validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(parameter.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
 [ValidateActionParameters]
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody][Required]Product product)
```